# How can I get clicked keyboard data from inline keyboard and answercallBackQuery or answerInlineQuery in laravel telegram-bot-sdk?

Tags: php, laravel

I setwebhook in there!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/su8LF.png)

web.php

```
Route::post('/webhook', function () {
   $update = Telegram::commandsHandler(true);
});
```

StartCommand command:

```
  public function handle()
         {
             $text = 'Assalomu alaykum botimizga xush kelibsiz!'.chr(10).chr(10);
             $text .= 'Bugungi taomni baholang!'.chr(10).chr(10);
     
             $update = Telegram::getWebhookUpdate();
             $chat_id = $update->getMessage()->getChat()->getId();
     
             $keyboard = array(
     array(
            array('text'=>'1','callback_data'=>"1"),
            array('text'=>'2','callback_data'=>"2"),
            array('text'=>'3','callback_data'=>"3"),
            array('text'=>'4','callback_data'=>"4"),
            array('text'=>'5','callback_data'=>"5"),
                 )
             );
     
             $reply_markup = Keyboard::inlineButton([
                 'inline_keyboard' => $keyboard,
                 'resize_keyboard' => true,
                 'one_time_keyboard' => true,
                'hideInlineKeyboard' =>false,
             ]);
    
     Telegram::sendMessage([
                 'chat_id' => $chat_id,
                'text' => $text,
                'reply_markup' => $reply_markup
             ]);
        }
```

If the user clicks 1 or other numbers, the bot answers you clicked 1,... .`

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76545475/edit). Thanks in advance.